# Linked Component Title in CM DB

Tags: 2011

We are getting a weird issue with the title of linked component. We have a promo component which has a component link for Department component. AS per requirement, we have a Stored Procedure which runs in Tridion CM DB which gets the details of promo component and gets the title of linked department component as well and we display the same in an application. Now the issue is, sometimes the linked component title is available inside the CM DB and sometimes it is not at all available. Ideally xlink:title should be available in DB but it is not. Why is this happening? We are using tridion 2011 sp1.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, perhaps you could add some more details.  It looks like you're using direct database queries (Stored proc) to get data from the broker database, when you should be using the content delivery api / content delivery webservice. Perhaps you could clarify

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Tridion in an unsupported way. Such a question (and associated answers) are unlikely to be helpful to the rest of the community.

Answer (score 4):

If I am reading your question correctly, then it appears that you are using a custom application to read content from the Tridion Content Manager database using a Stored Procedure.

As John mentions above, **it is strongly recommended that any integration is performed through one of the supported APIs** - in this case, reading from the Content Manager, then you should use the Content Manager Core Webservice. More details can be found in the [Core Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HjNl.png) section with the online documentation (login required).

The approach that you are currently taking is not supported and *may* affect your support agreement. At the very least, you risk your application breaking following an upgrade or hotfix application.

However, as a response to the issue that you are seeing, I suspect that this is because the 'Title' of a Component Link is only added after the Component is opened/re-loaded **after** being saved for the first time.

For example, when you first create the Component (containing the Component Link):
[image]

You get the following code in the 'Source' of the Component (without the 'Title' attribute):
[image]

You will notice that the title attribute is not present.

I suspect that if you used the Core Service to open the Component, then it would add in the 'Title' of the linked Component when the source Component is 'opened'.

However, as you are querying the Content Manager database directly, then the process of adding in the 'Title' has not had chance to run, and this is why the Title is missing in some instanced.

You could verify this theory by looking a the version history of the Components that are missing the 'Title'. If correct, then all of the Components with this problem should only have a single version.

Comment: This has been developed way back in 2009 when core service was not in picture with Tridion r 5.3 and still this is being used. Down the line we have a plan to redesign the same with core services.